# How to change route of a vuejs page based on a value stored in vuex?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuex, reactive

I have stored this variable companyName in my vuex store. And I want to change the default loading page written inside the router.js file whenever its value changes.

```
component: function () {
                    return (store.state.user.companyName ? import("A.vue") : import("B.vue"));
                }
            },
```

Here is my vuex file

```
const actions = {
fetchUserData({commit}) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        UserDetails.getUser().then(response => {
            userDetails.name = response.data.name,
            UserDetails.getCompany().then(response => {
                userDetails.companyName = response.data.companyName
                commit('updateUserDetails', userDetails)
            })
            resolve(response)
        })
    })
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

You can create a page wrapper  contains and call the 2 pages you want to show and use v-if 
for example:

```
// Page Wrapper
<template>
<div>
   <Page1 v-if="$store.state.user.companyName === 'test'">
   <Page2 v-if="$store.state.user.companyName === 'test2'">
</div>
</template>
```